# Java Multithreading null pointer exception

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I'm working on this program and I keep getting a NullPointerException and I'm not sure why.

```
//Constructor

public LongTask(SharedResults sharedData,int start, int end)
{
    super("Thread");
    sharedData=this.sharedData;
    start = this.start;
    end=this.end;

}

//Run

public void run() {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int num = start; num<=end;num++)
            {
        sum+=num;

        try {
            Thread.sleep((long)(5000*Math.random()));
            }

            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {}
        sharedData.addToResult(sum);
        }
}
}
```

I end up getting a NullPointerException error.  It looks like my data is not being summed correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is:

```
sharedData=this.sharedData;
start = this.start;
end=this.end;
```

You are assigned the method level variables to have the values of the class level variables. This needs to be the other way around. The way it's written now, your SharedData will always be `null` because it's never getting assigned in the constructor. So later, when you call

```
 sharedData.addToResult(sum);
```

You are calling attempting to call this method on a null object reference, which explains your `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Ye you need to assign the field variables not the parameter values, you need to do it the other way around ex. "this.sharedData = sharedData" if this part confuses you, use different variable names as parameter values.